# Adding dynamic values in an input box using watin for a web based application

Tags: watin

I am working on a web based application which takes care of online orders placed by customers .

we are using watin for sanity.This is what my code reads

mybrowser.TextField(Find.ByName("searchBox")).Value = "milk";

mybrowser.Image(Find.ByName("search")).Click();

In the input field i want to add any string value(e.g meat/bakery) of X length

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question you want to be able to generate and input a string of a specific, given length X. Here is some code I wrote a while ago for that.

```
    public static string GetRandomString(int length)
    {
        StringBuilder randomString = new StringBuilder();
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            randomString.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * randomNumber.NextDouble() + 65))));
        }
        return randomString.ToString();
    }
```

If you want to pick from a specific list of items I would use code like this

```
         public static string GenerateRandomFood()
         {
             string[] foods = {"Bread", "Cheese", "Milk", };

             // There are 3 food names
             return foods[GetRandomInt(0, 2)];
         }
```

Hope that is what you are after.